# In which of the MGS series are you able to equip the Stun Knife?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-series

I have only played MGS4. Is the Stun Knife available in any other game in the series?

Answer (score 1):

From the ['Blade Weapons' wikia page](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Blade_weapons#Stun_knife):

> [...] was used by Solid Snake during Liquid Ocelot's Insurrection in 2014 [...]

So it first appears in MGS4, however...

> Upon recruiting Old Snake in Metal Gear Solid: Portable Ops Plus, the stun knife can also be procured.

So it's available in both MGS4 and Portable Ops Plus

Answer (score 0):

It is available in MGS: Peace Walker (HD)

I presume it is also present in Portable Ops (+) since the engine is the same.